# ListBox has set datasource but Refresh does nothing

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datatable, listbox-control

I seem to be misunderstanding the ListBox.Refresh() method and I was hoping someone could help me out.

What I am trying to do:
I want to load a listbox's data (source = table of a sql database) upon initialization of a windows form. Also when the user adds data to the database I would like the listbox to update.

Logic:
I have a sql database as my source, it is set as:

```
listBoxDays.DataSource = DBQuery.informationRetreval().DefaultView;
```

DBquery.informationRetreval() is a static method within the my DBQuery static class. All it does is set up a table from the database and then returns the table.

I set the datasource within the same method as the initializeComponent (so my listbox will load with the existing data):

```
public Settings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBoxDays.DataSource = DBQuery.informationRetreval().DefaultView;
    }
```

When the user adds more data: I call a method in which I add the data to the database and then I call:

```
    listBoxDays.Refresh(); //update listbox
```

The Problem:
This does not update the listbox. Upon initialization of my listbox the data will populate but after it will not change (hence refresh does not work). Why is that? I could set the DataSource again but that feels sloppy. After looking into some of the documentation I noticed the event handler DataSourceChanged which maybe more for what I am looking for. Nevertheless why wouldn't refresh work?

Thank you for your patience. Please let me know if I need to be more clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Refresh(): Forces the control to invalidate its client area and immediately
>   redraw itself and any child controls.

Refresh will not rebind your control, it will just cause the control to be redrawn. You will have to set the `DataSource` again with

```
listBoxDays.DataSource = DBQuery.informationRetreval().DefaultView;
```

and re-bind it.

Source: [Microsoft MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.refresh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Would it make more sense to use the event handler: ListControl.DataSourceChanged... occurs when the datasource changes?

Comment: I would say to create a method that will clean and bind the control and call it from the InitializeComponent() and from everywhere else you are using the .Refresh() function.

Comment: Also, at least in the version of VB i'm working with I got an error saying you cannot clear items when data is bound to a datasource. All I had to add was a add a line the said `Listbox.DataSource = Nothing` and then clear my items and rebind my data

Comment: ListBox.Items.Clear() throws Exception when DataSource set. The working code is @RandomUs1r's answer.

Comment: To expand on @guneysus's post: You cannot clear Items if they were brought in using ListBox.DataSource. If you want to use ListBox.Items.Clear(), you'll have to bring them in using ListBox.Items.Add(object item).

Answer (score 16):

It'll only refresh when objects have changed (ex. a different query), not the data.  You can do this:

```
listBoxDays.DataSource = null;
listBoxDays.DataSource = DBQuery.informationRetreval().DefaultView;
```

to refresh it... everytime you need to.

Comment: great! i don't why we have to do this

Comment: This: "it'll only refresh when objects have changed (ex. a different query), not the data" is missing in many other answers regarding this question/problem