# Why does removing a listbox Item crash the second time through the loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, listbox, crash, windows-ce

This has been an ongoing problem; In the code below, the old code (which also failed) is commented out. The new code behaves the same way, though:

```
private void UpdateGUIAfterTableSend(String listboxVal)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend");
    try
    {
        //listBoxWork.DataSource = null; // <= This (at one time, anyway) seemed necessary to circumvent "Value does not fall within the expected range"
        //// Failing ignominiously; question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28439941/why-is-this-array-list-removal-code-failing
        //for (int i = listBoxWork.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) // try a foreach instead?
        //{
        //    if (listBoxWork.Items[i].ToString().Contains(listboxVal))
        //    {
        //        listBoxWork.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        //    }
        //}
        BindingSource bs = listBoxWork.DataSource as BindingSource;
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#2");
        for (int i = bs.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            if (bs[i].ToString().Contains(listboxVal))
            {
                bs.RemoveAt(i);
                ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#3");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format("{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend: {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
}
```

It seems that the second time through the for loop, the app suddenly crashes. I say this because the log file shows "Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#3" but not the log msg from the catch block. So it must be crashing on the second iteration of the four loop (prior to "Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#3" being logged again). So once it crashes it's goodnight, Irene: it crashes so hard and fast it doesn't even log the catch block's log msg. Or is there another explanation?

But more importantly: Why does the second check of "Contains" or the second attemtp to Remove (shouldn't happen in my test case, where the listbox has only one item) detonate a code-gone-wild nuclear device?

This is the last of the log file after the crash:

```
Date: 2/11/2015 12:45:34 PM
Message: Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend

Date: 2/11/2015 12:45:34 PM
Message: Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#2

Date: 2/11/2015 12:45:34 PM
Message: Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#3

Date: 2/11/2015 12:45:34 PM
Message: From application-wide exception handler: System.InvalidOperationException: InvalidOperationException
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
   at HHS.frmMain.SendDeliveries()
   at HHS.frmMain.menuItemSEND_Deliveries_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc(Control ctlThis, WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at HHS.Program.Main()
```

### UPDATE

I added another log msg, just before the "RemoveAt" line, and get what I was expecting:

```
Date: 2/11/2015 1:36:53 PM
Message: About to remove listbox value DSD_3_20150209151047000 at index 0
```

...but it crashes immediately after that, so Rake36 must be right.

### UPDATE 2

I was somewhat confident this would work:

```
private void UpdateGUIAfterTableSend(String listboxVal)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend");
    try
    {
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("About to remove listbox value {0}", listboxVal));
        listBoxWork.Items.RemoveAt(listBoxWork.Items.IndexOf(listboxVal));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format("{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend: {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
}
```

...but my hopes were dashed when I heard the tell-tale "bong!" and then hunted this up in the log file:

```
Message: About to remove listbox value DSD_3_20150209151047000

Date: 2/11/2015 1:58:18 PM
Message: From frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.; Inner Ex: ; Stack Trace:    at System.Collections.ArrayList.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection.RemoveAt(Int32 index)
   at HHS.frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend(String listboxVal)
   at HHS.frmMain.SendDeliveries()
   at HHS.frmMain.menuItemSEND_Deliveries_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc(Control ctlThis, WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at HHS.Program.Main()


Date: 2/11/2015 1:58:19 PM
Message: From application-wide exception handler: System.InvalidOperationException: InvalidOperationException
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
   at HHS.frmMain.SendDeliveries()
   at HHS.frmMain.menuItemSEND_Deliveries_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Menu.ProcessMnuProc(Control ctlThis, WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at HHS.Program.Main()
```

I even added this just before the "RemoveAt" line:

```
listBoxWork.DataSource = null;
```

...but it made no difference.

### UPDATE 3

This (inspired by Ravi M Patel) also crashes:

```
private void UpdateGUIAfterTableSend(String listboxVal)
{
    ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend");
    try
    {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = listBoxWork.DataSource;
        for (int i = bs.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (bs[i].ToString().Contains(listboxVal))
            {
                ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("About to remove listbox value {0} at index {1}", listboxVal, i));
                bs.RemoveAt(i);
                ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog("Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#3");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        String msgInnerExAndStackTrace = String.Format("{0}; Inner Ex: {1}; Stack Trace: {2}", ex.Message, ex.InnerException, ex.StackTrace);
        ExceptionLoggingService.Instance.WriteLog(String.Format("From frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend: {0}", msgInnerExAndStackTrace));
    }
}
```

...and the log file's (pertinent) contents are:

```
Date: 2/11/2015 2:09:59 PM
Message: About to remove listbox value DSD_3_20150209151047000 at index 0

Date: 2/11/2015 2:09:59 PM
Message: Reached frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend#3

Date: 2/11/2015 2:09:59 PM
Message: From application-wide exception handler: System.InvalidOperationException: InvalidOperationException
   at System.Collections.ArrayList.ArrayListEnumeratorSimple.MoveNext()
   at HHS.frmMain.SendDeliveries()
```

### UPDATE 4

For the real fix, see [How can I remove more than one item from a listbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28490594/how-can-i-remove-more-than-one-item-from-a-listbox)

Comment: any special reason to use --i instead of i-- ?

Comment: @TaW thought of that too, wouldn't make any difference in this case.

Comment: Yeah, I changed it to i-- and it acts exactly the same (very naughtily). I think Rake and Ramblin' Man is right - see the Update.

Comment: If the lb is databound you should nor even try to remove items from it but only from the datasource!! You may want to [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404992/remove-selected-item-in-combobox/28428484#28428484) for an example with a combobox..

Comment: Can you tell us what the listbox is bound to? Is it an arraylist? One more thing, if you replace log message with message boxes, do you see the same messages?

Comment: It is a list of string returned from a database query.

Comment: Ok, what is the c# type of that query? ArrayList, DataTable...??

Comment: It returns a list of strings.

Comment: I am thrilled almost beyond description to know that I will never again work on this antiquated technology (99.999% certainty).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update 2

Replace code in your try{} block with the following:

```
BindingSource bs = listBoxWork.DataSource as BindingSource;
List<string> values = bs.DataSource as List<string>;
values.RemoveAll(v => v.Contains(listboxVal));
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

### Update

@TaW is right. I am taking a wild guess at the problem. When you remove an element from the datasource, it is also updating the ListBox. And since you are removing the **selected** value, the UI is trying to select the next value and **bang**, there is none.

So to make this work, you should rather do this. Let say you have bound your list box to an arraylist called `values`.

Now in your method remove items from `values` instead of the BindingSource. In your case if are sure that there will be only one value in the list. All you have to do is `values.Remove("valuetoremove");` Then reset bindings like so.

```
ArrayList values = bs.DataSource as ArrayList;
values.Remove("valuetoremove");
bs.ResetBindings(false);
```

You may disregard my answer below. I think the datasource you are typecasting is already of type BindingSource so you're good with you original statement. `BindingSource bs = listBoxWork.DataSource as BindingSource;` I wouldn't know as we can't see the whole code here.

---

If you want the right behavior out of the bindingsource. You better use it this way.

```
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = listBoxWork.DataSource;
```

try it with your original code.

Comment: I don't see how your code in the Update would affect the listbox items. It seems to take a copy of the values and then remove the one *from itself* that is to be removed...?

Comment: May be it's they way i wrote it got you confused. I updated it, check it now.

Comment: I'll try it, but it still seems to me that the only thing being updated is the temporary list, for how can ResetBindings() know what to reset to? It should have no knowledge that "values" copied its values.

Comment: It does and I'll tell you how. bs.DataSource is nothing but the reference to the list of string you from the db. Somewhere in your code, you would have written something like this : `BindingSource bs = new BindingSource(); bs.DataSource = values; (which you got from db) listBoxWork.DataSource = bs;` All we are doing is getting this reference back and updating the underlying list. We don't need to give the updated list back to `bs` because it already has it. So we are calling its `ResetBindings()` method which causes the UI to be updated.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is coming from an entirely different place than the logic that you are showing. It is the application wide exception handler that is triggered and not the exception handler that would create trace "From frmMain.UpdateGUIAfterTableSend". The exception is most likely because the binding has side effects. Take a look at the bindingsource and the events that you attached to it.
Also add a trace after the removal so you can see that the removal is really happening or use a debugger.Your Update 3 shows that the remove is really happening.

Add more traces in SendDeliveries. Your problem is in there

Comment: Can't use a debugger - this is an 1879-era Windows CE project. Version of .NET is -0.13 or so.

Comment: Still the main point of this answer is that you crash because you change the datasource from the wrong end, that is from the bound control instead of from the datasource itself..

Comment: This method is called at the very end of SendDeliveries(); it makes it all the way through there (I do have several log msgs in there, too).

Answer (score 1):

You can't destroy elements in the list as you're iterating. You need to collect the items you want to remove first, then iterate through those, deleting from the original list in the process.

Useful pattern:

```
Items.RemoveAt(Items.IndexOf(itemToDelete))
```

Comment: He is using a reverse for loop. It shouldn't create any problems.

Comment: You can not do that in a foreach loop but you can in a for next loop. So this answer is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you can do this:

```
List<string> list = (List<string>) listBoxWork.DataSource;
```

you should be able to do this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list[i].Contains(listboxVal))
        {
            list.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }

    listBox1.DataSource = null;
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.DataSource = list;
```

But I doubt that your `DataSource` **is** actually a `List<string>` as this would simply not work. (Only the lengths of the strings would show!)

So you ought to modify the code to fit the type of your **actual** `DataSource`!

If it were something like:

```
List<AString> list = new List<AString>();
```

of a class like :

```
class AString
{
    public string s { get; set; }
    public AString(string s_) { s = s_; }
    public override string ToString()  {   return s;    }
}
```

then this would work:

```
    for (int i = list.Count - 1; i > 0;  i--)
    {
        if (list[i].s.Contains(listboxVal))
        {
            list.RemoveAt(i); 
        }
    }       
    listBox1.DataSource = null;
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    listBox1.DataSource = list;
```

Note that the `ListBox` [doesn't automatically update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969650/listbox-has-set-datasource-but-refresh-does-nothing) when the `DataSource` is modified.

Instead of doing this rather unsatisfactory roundtrip you can use a `BindingList`:

```
    BindingList<AString> data = new BindingList<AString>();
    foreach (AStrings in list) data.Add(s);
    listBox1.DataSource = data;

    for (int i = data.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        if (data[i].s.Contains("8"))
        {
            data.RemoveAt(i); // (list[i]);
        }
    }
```

Now the removals are reflected right away..